# backbone.js fetch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am facing a problem with getting a response in fetch function of backbone.js. I am using Backbone.js with rails.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.projectPerformanceReport.fetch({
        success: function(e) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            window.questionListView = new QuestionListView;
            window.questionListView.render();
            window.headerView = new HeaderView;
            window.headerView.render();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

There is already a URL set for the fetch method and it does make a request to online server which returns a JSON object. I checked by hitting that request independently in new tab and it worked fine. Also the JSON object returned is valid. But when i run this page i always get popup of 'Error'?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: The [`error` callback](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch) gets two parameters, is there anything in the second one?

Comment: Nopes... I checked.. Its empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay

I got what was the issue.....  The thing that was happening was, The Java_Servlet which i was calling to get the JSON object was returning the data in text format instead of JSON... (But it was a valid JSON string)... and while calling the ajax method i had set the type as 'json' so it was failing.

Thanks to everyone who read my question and thought for a solution.

But one strange thing which i observed was, same code was working in production and not in my local machine??? Does anyone have some idea on why it could be behaving like that..???

Thanks :) Now i can sleep properly!!